# Server is not responding when client is trying to connect to it

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, socket.io, client

I'm new to Socket.io. I'm trying to establish a connection to the server. But the connection event is not responding. Is there anything I'm doing wrong that I am unable to figure out? Here is my code for the server and client side.

client.html

```
<script src="http://localhost:5000/socket.io/socket.io.js">
    const io = require('socket.io-client');
    const socket = io.connect("https://localhost:5000");
    socket.on("connect", () => {
        console.log(socket.id);
    });
</script>
```

server.js

```
const app = require('express')();
const server = require('http').createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server);
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    console.log(socket.id);
  });
server.listen(5000,()=>{
    console.log("Server is listening at port 5000...");
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not provide any error messages which makes it incredibly hard to help you. Usually, if you work with Code you wrote for the Browser you can debug/see errors with the Browser Console (Which usually opens once you open F12). I recommend you for the next post to provide some information on the errors you are getting.

The possible errors I can think of in your code:

1. Split SocketIoClient Script Tag and Execution Tag. Since you put src at the source Tag the code inside the tag will not run at all. try something like this:

```
    <script src="yourSocketIoLocation/socket.io.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      const socket = io.connect("http://localhost:5000");
      socket.on("connect", () => {
          console.log(socket.id);
      });
     </script>
```

2. Require doesn't actually work in Clientside Javascript it only works in NodeJs and in this case you actually don't even need it. As you can see in the above Example I just removed it and it should work. An Error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined` should not show up again.
3. CORS. Your Server Code looks fine, but for it to work I had to add CORS Settings like this:

```
const app = require('express')();
const server = require('http').createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: "http://127.0.0.1:8080",
    methods: ["GET", "POST"]
  }
});
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    console.log(socket.id);
  });
server.listen(5000,()=>{
    console.log("Server is listening at port 5000...");
})
```

You can find documentation on the cors Settings here: https://socket.io/docs/v3/handling-cors/
Just swap the `http://127.0.0.1:8080` with your actual webserver location.